# How do I delete an asset with module or plugin

Tags: assets, modules

I'm trying to clean-up the assets in a specific folder that aren't being used at all, i.e. aren't related to anything.

I got the list O.K. just using this

```
$assets = Asset::find()->volume('artists')->kind('image')->limit(50000)->ids();

$assetsToDelete = [];

foreach($assets as $asset) {
    $results = (new Query())
        ->select(['id'])
        ->from(['{{%relations}}'])
        ->where(['targetId' => $asset])
        ->orWhere(['sourceId' => $asset])
        ->all();

    if (!count($results)) {
        $assetsToDelete[]  = $asset;
    }     
}

return  $this->asJson($assetsToDelete);
```

Right now I'm just returning all the ids in an array but I'm hoping to find a command to delete the element AND delete the stored asset on the server

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how well it'd go with 50,000 Assets, but you should just be able to call `Craft::$app->elements->deleteElement($asset)` for each one, or `Craft::$app->elements->deleteElementById($asset->id)`, as seen in the [Elements Class Reference](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-deleteelement).

Comment: Will that delete the actual file off the server as well? Seems like it would just delete the element in the database

Comment: @KeithMancuso it'll eventually trigger the asset element's `afterDelete` method which will take care of deleting the file: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/elements/Asset.php#L1292-L1300